# Multiple property options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a gallery of shirts, and with a select button I can show only shirts with a specific color (if the user selects Green, I show only shirts which have green in them).

```
<div id="fancybox-thumbs">
    <ul>
        <li class="shirt" color="green"><a class="fancybox-buttons" data-fancybox-group="button" href="images/Slike/Majice/VEM/Logo/DSC_0126-logo.jpg"><img src="images/Slike/Majice/VEM/Logo/DSC_0126-thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>

        <li class="shirt" color="blue"><a class="fancybox-buttons" data-fancybox-group="button" href="images/Slike/Majice/VEM/Logo/DSC_0128-logo.jpg"><img src="images/Slike/Majice/VEM/Logo/DSC_0128-thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>

        <li class="shirt" color="yellow"><a class="fancybox-buttons" data-fancybox-group="button" href="images/Slike/Majice/VEM/Logo/DSC_0130-logo.jpg"><img src="images/Slike/Majice/VEM/Logo/DSC_0130-thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>

    </ul></div>
```

My question is, is it possible I set the color label of one of the "li" to let's say green and blue, and then show it if either green or blue is selected from the select button?

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$('document').ready(function() {

    $('#colorForm').change(function() {

        var selectedColor = $('#colorForm option:selected').val();

        if( selectedColor == 'all' ) {
            $('li.shirt').show(1000);
        } else {
            $('li.shirt[color*="'+selectedColor+'"]').show(1000);
            $('li.shirt[color!="'+selectedColor+'"]').hide(1000);
        }

    });

});
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data attributes seems more approriate (and more valid)

```
<li class="shirt" data-color="green">
```

and then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#colorForm').on('change', function () {
        var selectedColor = this.value;

        if (selectedColor == 'all') {
            $('li.shirt').show(1000);
        } else {
            $('li.shirt').each(function(_,li) {
                var flag = $.inArray(selectedColor, $(li).data('color').split(/\s+/)) != -1;
                $(li)[flag ? 'show':'hide'](1000);
            });
        }
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/24KUv/2/)

Comment: That worked beautifully. Thank you very much kind sir. Could you briefly explain what does the code in the "else" statement do?

Comment: It iterates over the LI elements, checking if the value from the select exists in the data attribute, and show or hides accordingly.

Comment: Oh ok, very nice. This may be a bit far fetched question, but how can I change the fancybox code so it then scrolls through just the selected colors? because now now when I click on an image to enlarge it, it still scrolls through all images, not just the color I selected. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely. You just need a bit of cleverness.

Have your element like this:

```
<li class="shirt" color="green blue"> ... </li>
```

Then, change your jQuery to this:

```
$('li.shirt').hide(1000);
$('li.shirt[color~=green]').stop().show(1000);
```

The `~=` attribute selector is kind of like how classes work. You have several words, separated by spaces, and `~=` looks for one such word.

Comment: Thank your for your comment. I am new to jQuery, and I'm not sure how tu build this selector of which you speak. Can you help me out please?

Comment: Well, right now you have the `selectedColor` variable. Just splice it in in place of the hardcoded one. Something like `$("li.shirt[color~="+selectedColor+"]")` should do it.